# vb check if 2 strings have 2 not equal chars

Tags: vb.net, string, char

for example we have 2 Strings.

```
string1 = "abcdef"
string2 = "abvdtf"
```

How i can check now if more than 2 chars are different, it should return me false.

Comment: character duplication allows?

Comment: I don't the coding of vb. but I can give you logic if you like

Comment: A logic would be great ;)

Comment: 1) Split the both string into array of character
2) Find non Intersect 
(var nonintersect = array1.Except(array2).Union( array2.Except(array1)); //this is c# code)

if nointersect length is greater than 0 your both string do not match

Comment: will the two strings be of the same length always?

Comment: No, they have a different length

Comment: then if string1 = "abcdefghi" and string2 ="abcdefg" what output do you want? and if string1= "abcdefghi" and string2="abcdrxs" then what output do you want. pls tell me so that i can help you

Comment: In short, provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  YOU have to tell us what the requirements are.  Vague descriptions are not enough because code has to be specific.

Comment: exactly. in the example you provide two 6-chars string. what if they are of different lengths? what outputs do you want then? You have to be more specific than that

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function:-

```
Public Function Compare(s1 As String, s2 As String, errorlimit As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim ErrorCount As Integer = 0
    For x As Integer = 0 To s1.Length - 1
        If s1(x) <> s2(x) Then
            ErrorCount += 1
        End If
    Next
    If ErrorCount > errorlimit Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

A return value of **true** means that either the strings are identical or the number of different characters is less than the error limit specified. A return value of **false** means that the number of different characters exceeds the error limit specified.